# int array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, int, default-value

I have here a simple question related to Java.
Let's say you have an int array as instance variable:

```
int[] in = new int[5];
```

So, now by default it contains 5 zeros.
But what if you have the same array as local variable. Does it get initialized to zeros? That is not a homework, I am learning Java language.
Best regards

Comment: But I want some discussion to let me realize the underlying logic, but not only memorize the answer.

Comment: @uml for better understanding see rohit jains answer :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**First thing** to understand  is that, *local varibles* are stored on *stack* which are not initialized explicitly with their default values. While *instance variables* are stored on *Heap*, and they are by default initialized with their *default value*.

Also, *objects* are also created on *Heap*, regardless of whether an instance reference variable is holding its reference, or a local reference variable.

---

Now, what happens is, when you declare your array reference like this as local variable, and initialize it with an array: -

```
int[] in = new int[5];
```

The array reference `(in)` is stored on *stack*, and a memory is allocated for array capable of holding *5 integer* elements on *heap* (Remember, objects are created on Heap). Then, 5 contiguous memory location `(size = 5)`, for storing *integer* value are allocated on *Heap*. And each *index* on array object holds a *reference* to those memory location in sequence. Then the array reference points to that array. So, since memory for 5 integer values are allocated on Heap, they are initialized to their default value.

And also, when you declare your array reference, and don't initialize it with any array object: -

```
int[] in;
```

The array reference is created on *Stack* (as it is a local variable), but it does not gets initialized to an array by default, and neither to `null`, as is the case with instance variables.

---

So, this is how allocation looks like when you use the first way of array declaration and initialization: -

```
"Your array reference"
     "on stack"    

       |    |          "Array object on Heap"
       +----+                  
       | in |---------->  ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
       +----+
       "Stack"                  "Heap"
```

Comment: In short, if you do, `int[] in = new int[5]`, the array will get initialized to default values.

Comment: *And each index on array object holds a reference to those memory location in sequence.* Not really. The index is simply an offset from the array's starting point.

Answer (score 5):

It is the same thing if you do :

`int[] in = new int[5]` as instance variable or local variable. The array object `in` will contain zeros in both cases.

Difference would be if you would do something like :

1. Instance variable : `int[] in`; (it is initialized with **null**), and the `in` object will live in *heap space*.
2. Local variable : `int[] in`; (it has to be initialized by the user) will live in *stack*

Answer (score 3):

For primitive type arrays it is initialized to their default values.
In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html) it says :

> a single-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and
>   each component of the array is initialized to its default value

For the integer type default value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you initialise an array the contents will be set to the default value for that type, for `int` it would be 0 and for a reference type it would be `null`.

If you initialise an array and inspect the contents you can see this for yourself:

```
...
final int[] in = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(in[i]);
}
...
```

This will print:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

yes

```
public void method() {
    int[] in = new int[5];
    System.out.pritnln(in[0]); //output in 0
}
```

In this case, your **Array is a local variable**, all you need is to **initialize your array**. once you initialize you array, **voila** your **array element**s get their **default values**.

Comment: Why does it contain zeros? The local variable needs to be initialized explicitly.

Comment: your array is the local variable in this case, not its elements, you initialized you array so, the element sin the array get their default values :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter whether the declared array in an instance variable or a local variable it will get initialized to the default value.

Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created.

As per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)

`An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for all its components.`

Answer (score 0):

THe Array Doesn't Contain 5 zeroes when you instantiate it as a local variable.

Comment: So, what does it contain? Garbage?