# int datatype initialization : Array vs Regular

Tags: java, arrays

```
class returntest
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        int a;
        System.out.println(a); //Line 1

        int b[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println(b[1]); //Line 2
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error (obviously) at Line 1 stating that the variable may not have been initialized.

I know all int array elements are initialized to 0 by default (so Line 2 compiles successfully) but my question is why cant compiler apply the same logic (of setting to 0 for all ints) to regular (non-array) int variables.

Is there any limitation that prohibits the compiler from doing that ?

Comment: Please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511702/int-array-initialization

Comment: In future, please format your code appropriately when you ask a question - see http://tinyurl.com/so-list. It also helps if you use conventional names (unlike `returntest`) even for dummy code - it's just less distracting that way.

Answer (score 4):

Local variables defined in a block of statements always must be initialized before use.

But member variables, those defined directly in the body of a class, are automatically initialized to 0 when the object is created.

Useful thread [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/404254/java/java/difference-integer-integer-array).

Answer (score 2):

From [here:-](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a
>   default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot
>   initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to
>   assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an
>   uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

When variable scope is local then you must initialized local variable.

When you declare any **local/block variable**, they didn’t get the default values. They must assigned some value before accessing it other wise compiler will throw an error.

As you see in your code

```
int a; //Gives error because not assigned any value
```

> When you allocate resources for a local variable, Java doesn't write a value into the memory. The reason you get an error is because Java makes sure you give it a value before you use it. Sun realized that this can be a difficult problem to diagnose in C code, because you don't get help from the compiler, so they decided to check it at compile time.

Refer this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/399519/java/java/local-variable-initialized)

Answer (score 0):

This was a language design decision.

Having a default initialisation for local variables could hide errors. The usage of a local variable implies you want to set it first. Simple cases of forgetting to set it, or setting it only in `if` then are captured.